# add entire folder to sourcesafe?

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

I have a folder with various files and subfolders that I'd like to add to my sourcesafe 8.0 database.  In the SourceSafe explorer I can add files, but I don't see any options for adding an entire folder w/subfolders.  Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Drag it to the recycling bin.

Comment: It'll be just as safe there. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's been a while since I've used SourceSafe but I think you can just drag the folder into your project if I'm not mistaken.